# Can 2 pairs of Random variables, X - Y & X -Z have same absolute value of kendals tau. Can we simulate such data? Are there any real data examples?

Tags: simulation, correlation, rank

I have a theoretical situation where all data should have unique absolute value of kendals tau. I want to study the effect if this condition is not met.

Can we simulate data such that X,Y and X,Z have same absolute value of kendals tau. Also is there any real datas like this.

Regards